# Wildfly Injection depending on Condition (system-property)

Tags: dependency-injection, annotations, wildfly, system-properties

I am working with Wildfly atm and I am trying to get into @Annotations.
Having several implementations for some interfaces I want my application to pick a certain implementation depending on some condition (depending on a system-property, specified in my standalone.xml).

Can you point me to some hints to read up how to achieve such behaviour.

I don't want to directly specify the implementation as an @Alternative, since i want to bundle various injections with some system-property settings.

### standalone.xml

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="env" value="stage"/>
</system-properties>
```

### Interface

```
public interface LoginServerDao {
    public String test();
}
```

### Implementation 1

```
@MyCustomConditionalAnnotation(env = "live")
public class LoginServerDaoImpl implements LoginServerDao  {
    @Override
    public String test() {
        return "live";
    }
}
```

### Implementation 2

```
@MyCustomConditionalAnnotation(env = "stage")
public class DummyLoginServerDaoImpl implements LoginServerDao  {
    @Override
    public String test() {
        return "dummy";
    }
}
```

### Annotation Interface

```
@???
public @interface MyCustomConditionalAnnotation {

    String env() default "test";

    ???

}
```

I really appreciate any help with this (or refering to some completely different solution/pattern I might not even have thought about).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You likely want to have a look at [CDI](http://www.cdi-spec.org/learn/). WildFly uses [Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/) for it's implementation.

Comment: @James Thank you for your response! I am very sorry I was sure I already replied! Must have missed to hit the "Add Comment" button. About your hint: That is exactly what I am trying to use. I am already using filters, startup Hooks and Injection for my DAOs. However, I can't find a hint about how to achieve what I was trying to to in my upper example. Maybe Producer-Methods is what I am looking for.
Anyway, thank you very much for the reply! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem!

> **Stereotypes**

Found the answer on stackoverflow here: [Disable @Alternative classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250622/disable-alternative-classes)

> @Cassio Mazzochi Molin explained under **Writing your own alternative stereotype**